# SSSD list allowed users only

Tags: ubuntu, centos, ldap

We are using SSSD for authentication using LDAP. And I filter the user access using **simple_allow_groups** as follows:

```
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = Computer Admins
```

(**Note**: Computer Admins is a LDAP group)

Is it possible to get a list of **ONLY** allowed users using **getent** or something else??

There is an option enumeration, but this lists **all** users from LDAP. I am only interested in the **allowed** users.